# Pushing a key that points to another array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried the following:

```
$myArray = array();
array_push($myArray,"A"=>array("x","y"));
```

I get prompted with this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

- Is the above possible to do in PHP?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a more conventional way of doing this?

Comment: That's invalid syntax and you can't use `array_push()` to specify a key.

Comment: @AbraCadaver How could I go about adding a key pointing to another array into $myArray? without using the push function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never liked `array_push()` and never use it.  That's invalid syntax and you can't use `array_push()` to specify a key.  To specify a key:

```
$myArray["A"] = array("x","y");
```

Which will yield:

```
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
        )
)
```

Unless you really want an array like this:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [A] => Array
                (
                    [0] => x
                    [1] => y
                )
        )
)
```

Then you would do:

```
array_push($myArray, array("A" => array("x","y")));
```

But that's probably not what you want.  I always go with `$array[]` or `$array['key']` syntax.

Comment: will that create a key 'A'? or would 'A' have to be in the array before this can be executed?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much :) Got it working Have a lovely evening